# Leg workout for someone without barbell or heavy DB?

Tags: workout-routines, bodybuilding, gym, legs, powerlifting

I live in a remote area of the city where there's no affordable gym nearby,in my apartment gym there are only DB upto 12.5kg,leg extn and curl machine.Any suggestions how to plan my leg workout with these light  free weights?
One idea is doing mad volumes of lunges and curls,is that a good idea?(I can't do pistol squats)

Comment: Hi Sagnik. I'm sure there are people who can answer this, but if I were you, I'd consider going back and accepting answers to all your old questions. You've asked a lot of questions, and got a lot of good answers, but never have you actually accepted any. I think people would be more motivated to help you if they saw that you don't just abandon a question as soon as someone replies.

Comment: You tagged powerlifting, are you looking to compete or train as a powerlifter?

Comment: Hello Alec what do mean by not accepting the answer?@Dark Hippo I tagged powerlifting because I took part in a competition and I know that Squat is an integral part of it ,so I'd like to have some suggestions from people who have been in lifting and know of any exercise they do when not able to do squats for any reason.

Comment: Sagnik, check out this question with respect to accepting answers. Let us know if it still doesn't make sense: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: C.Lange Oh thank you very much for the idea,I actually just found out what "accepting the answer" mean.I really had no idea.Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When it comes to powerlifting, nothing really beats out doing squats. You can do a lot of leg work but the technique you gain from doing squats is missed. That said, leg extensions and leg curls will work your quads and hamstrings. Personally, I find the leg extension to be uncomfortable.

One of my favourite quad building exercises is Bulgarian split squat or elevated split squats:

[image: Picture of split squat]

3 sets of 10-12 Bulgarian split squats usually leave me feeling like I can't walk the next day. I squat 165 kg for a 1 RM, but doing split squats at just bodyweight is a good challenge for myself. The unilateral aspect of the workout is also great for improving the weaknesses between the right and left leg muscles. With 12.5 kg dumbbells, I think these could be rather difficult.

Distance from the bench in a Bulgarian split squat is an individual thing, [however](https://www.coachmag.co.uk/leg-exercises/199/bulgarian-split-squat-instructions-form-tips-and-variations):

> The closer you stand to the bench, the more the Bulgarian split squat will emphasize your quads – though if you’re too close, it might give you some knee pain. Standing further away will tax your hip flexors more heavily, though it could also strain your groin. Experiment to find a distance that works for you.

The key to the exercise, from that same article, is this:

> Lower until your front thigh is almost horizontal, keeping your knee in line with your foot. Don't let your front knee travel beyond your toes.

Comment: Thanks for the answer,one more thing,do you think the distance from the bench as shown in the illustration above is correct?Don't you think he's slightly far ahead?

Comment: @sagnikdas, I personally think he's a bit far but it is still correct. I added a bit more verbiage about the distance from the bench. Thinking about mine, I'm rather close because my balance is poor. That could explain why it works my quads so much... the more you know!